# Keep alive a web app

Tags: web-services, windows-services, keep-alive

I have a small web application that is hosted on a shared hosting provider, but I need to run some simple background jobs, such as backing up a database and performing some data consistency checks.

If I had a dedicated server, I would just use a Windows Service for these tasks, but as it's shared hosting I have no such luxury.

I would ideally build a very simple web service onto the app, that would be called once per minute.  I could then build in the necessary logic to check the time and perform various scheduled tasks.  However, the obvious problem is how I get this web service to be called.

Are there any reasonable services out there that will call a web service on a scheduled basis?

Also any alternative solutions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this some more, and thought I'd post here for anyone with a similar problem.

I have created a very simple "Job" web page, that takes a URL parameter "?Interval=Minute", "?Interval=Hour", "?Interval=Daily" etc, and on the server I can then choose which jobs get run.

I will then setup separate "Cron Jobs" to call this page with the relevant url parameter, using one of many free Cron Job providers:

http://www.setcronjob.com/  (this is a good service, and has Job Failure email alerts)

This will allow my app to work much like a windows service, and run different jobs at defined intervals.